# Android xml layer-list not displayed correctly on some devices

Tags: android, xml, background, drawable, layer-list

I have an xml layer list drawable as a background for view, which is not displayed correctl on some devices.

I have a Huawei Ascend Mate with 4.2.2 which displays it ok.
On Asus phonepad tablet with 4.1.2 i see just the item shape stroke and dont see the other items.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@color/yellow_color" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:src="@drawable/dotted_bg"
            android:tileMode="repeat" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <stroke
                android:width="4dp"
                android:color="@color/yellow_color" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:src="@drawable/tls_bg" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: You may want to add some screenshots for illustration

Comment: Tnx Marcin, I'll add screenshots

Comment: what is @color/yellow_color  value?

Comment: I know it may sound silly but your color.xml file is in the right folder?

Comment: Tnx guys, everything was correct, instead of shape with not solid color issue. Apparently some android devices (versions) think that if no solid color was declared, it should be black.

Comment: Added resolution for the issue. See accepted answer.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I've fixed the issue. Apparently on some devices (android 4.0 and 4.1.1) the following code made all layers below the following shape to be overpainted with black color.

```
<item>
    <shape>
        <stroke
            android:width="4dp"
            android:color="@color/yellow_color" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

I have added transparent solid color for the shape and now it works fine.

```
<item>
    <shape>
        <stroke
            android:width="4dp"
            android:color="@color/yellow_color" />
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

**So never leave shapes with border without color as some devices will paint it black!**

Comment: oh!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
古いアンドロイドで真っ黒になっていて困っていました！！

Comment: OMG the android bugs!

Answer (score 0):

The phones use different API levels: 16 & 17. Make sure you don't have several *values* directories for specific targets (e.g. *values-v16* & *values-v17*).

Also, the items that are not displayed contain references to some drawables, so make sure the files are correct in every *drawable* directory for each screen dpi.

Comment: No, that's not the issue. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

That is probably because the drawable's  `android:src="@drawable/dotted_bg"`, `android:src="@drawable/dotted_bg"` and `android:src="@drawable/tls_bg"` are too big. Find the screen density of your device and check it's corresponding resource folder (e.g. `drawable-xhdpi`) and make your drawable's in that folder smaller.

Comment: No, thats not the issue. I have all images scaled for different screen density.