# LayerDrawable as background drawable does not work on minSdkVersion=15 or lower

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, layer-list, layerdrawable, bitmapdrawable

Although I couldn't find any SDK version constraints for `LayerDrawable` ([added in API level 1](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html)), the one I am using as a background acts differently depending on the minSdkVersion: if it is 15 or lower, the background is completely black, if it is 19 or higher (KitKat<), the layers are displayed as expected.

I am replacing the first item in the layer list programatically. Here is how I use the `LayerDrawable` class (although there shouldn't be any problem):

```
BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.xyz1);
bitmapDrawable.setColorFilter(getColor(), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
bitmapDrawable.setTileModeXY(TileMode.REPEAT, TileMode.REPEAT);

LayerDrawable bgDrwbl = (LayerDrawable) resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.mylayerdrawable);
bgDrwbl.setDrawableByLayerId(R.id.frameBitmap, bitmapDrawable);

int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    v.setBackgroundDrawable(bgDrwbl);
} else {
    v.setBackground(bgDrwbl);
}
```

Where mylayerdrawable looks like the following:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/frameBitmap"
    android:left="@dimen/card_frame_width"
    android:right="@dimen/card_frame_width"
    android:top="@dimen/card_frame_width"
    android:bottom="@dimen/card_frame_width" >

    <bitmap 
        android:tileMode="repeat"/>
</item>
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <stroke
            android:height="@dimen/card_frame_width"
            android:width="@dimen/card_frame_width"
            android:color="#000000" />

        <corners android:radius="4dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:left="0.4dp"
    android:right="0.4dp"
    android:top="0.4dp"
    android:bottom="0.4dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <stroke
            android:height="1.8dp"
            android:width="1.8dp"
            android:color="#EAEAEA" />

        <corners android:radius="4dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

While debugging I noticed the following missing members of `bgDrwbl` in minSdkVersion=15 compared to 19:

- `LayerDrawable.mLayerState.mAutoMirrored`
- `LayerDrawable.mLayoutDirection` (member of the base class: `Drawable`)

I don't know if any of them are crucial if someone uses LayerDrawable like me(?), but I neither got any warning nor find any suggestion on using `LayerDrawable`'s with different SDK versions. Do you have any hints?

Comment: does it work without calling `setDrawableByLayerId`?

Comment: It is the same without calling `setDrawableByLayerId()`. After playing around with the xml, I figured out, that the problem is not with the first layer (the bitmap layer), but with the second and third, that supposed to make a rounded frame around the bitmap. Removing the second AND third layer allows the bitmap to be shown, adding any of the two, makes the same problem (black background).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was too prejudiced with the `LayerDrawable`, as I had too much trouble making it work previously... But it turned out the problem has nothing to do with them or the minSdkVersion either, but lies within the shapes defined in the second and third item in case of some devices.
The same problem is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26561812/android-xml-layer-list-not-displayed-correctly-on-some-devices). In short:

> **So never leave shapes with border without color as some devices will
>   paint it black!**