# Incorrect items sizing in layer-list on pre-lollipop

Tags: android, layout, drawable, layer-list

I have a layer-list

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:right="2dp" android:left="2dp" android:bottom="2dp" android:top="2dp">
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_alert"/>
</item>

<item android:height="10dp" android:width="10dp" android:gravity="right|top">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <size android:height="10dp" android:width="10dp"/>
        <solid android:color="@color/navigation_drawer_notification_red_color"/>
    </shape>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

which shows this image

[image]

On lollipop and above everything is fine but on pre-lollipop red circle lose all sizing and padding attributes and image looks like this

[image]

I was looking for solution about 3 days and found nothing. I was trying to make my own toolbar layout and set to this imagebuuton scaleType="centerInside" but it didn't help. Could anyone help with this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, do you find a solution?

Comment: Hi, any solution? I'm also facing this issue.

Comment: @Nizam unfortunately no (

Comment: Ok. I'm now using a `FrameLayout` instead of `Drawable`.

Comment: Strange.....please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26561812/android-xml-layer-list-not-displayed-correctly-on-some-devices

Comment: did you get any solution?

Comment: I'm curious about the 2dp padding on the menu icon, can you provide the desired size of the entire drawable and the dp size of `ic_menu_alert.png`? I would assume that's 24dp

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Its best not to mention the `height` and `width` attributes in `layer-list`. When you use this as drawable in let's say an ImageView (**the width and height of the ImageView will override the one's mentioned in item/shape**).

You can use `top, bottom, left, right` to align your items in layer-list.

Note: *height and width attributes of item is supported only from API 23.*

Here is a working example (Tested in Android 7.0 and Android 4.4):

> sample.xml

```
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@+id/menu"
        android:left="16dp"
        android:right="16dp"
        android:gravity="center">
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/menu_icon" />
    </item>

    <item
        android:top="8dp"
        android:left="56dp"
        android:right="24dp"
        android:bottom="42dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

> main.xml

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:src="@drawable/sample"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
```

You can also use `wrap_content` for height & width in ImageView.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer:)

Comment: for all, don't forget about `scaleType` it's important for this trick.

Answer (score 2):

So i came up with a workable solution.  I have a layer-list drawable in `/drawable` and `/drawable-v21`.
The layer-list drawable in `/drawable-v21` contains a vector drawable.  The layer-list drawable in `/drawable` contains a .png .  It kind of defeats the purpose of using vector drawables but I had to do this to make it work in this one off case.